# How to perform git reset without losing some of the previous commits of a different branch

Tags: git

This is what my git log looks like right now:

```
git log --topo-order --reverse --pretty=oneline
50d035a5a12db8a0b23f4910a0e387f1ad38524c 0
49c9fef259eb54182da6d70fa0425474accb29e0 3
a1108badac40942296d9c9d734a561a645144914 7
1d7e5ea36224169db465d2e413c36895b02cafea 11
c327029ebf8c442c45aaef090236650b50fb5e47 1
c64fcac8dd676084caacea4e20a0409926be7054 5
1e1f9e389341e4161f2aa8d6f868346d76b21e33 9
e98be40ea2066b65a980de20200f036d2f37b027 2
e5f8dfe7c8bd9d7e02eae85a5c534e2d2db23f4a 6
1439d018ed902b9fde247b8568dc0df1539700e5 10
663f06f969597ddf1a6eeb9ec7921775c7f1bc02 Merge branch 'b'
a9b044cf716d6de969ed0649017bf61cae3e9421 4
b8a76a56c5f29c63b82dd823ec0b5b45abcd655c 8
6c266c5bb7106821b63d7e2ddf09347022f570ac 12
9162a13adb1642f8434d0211cf15bf4ac06b9a4b Merge branch 'd'
a704f3284be8289a50468215a12f5a214ae6ab4f (HEAD -> master, 
origin/master, origin/HEAD) Merge branch 'master' into c
```

I want to reset this to "1e1f9e389341e4161f2aa8d6f868346d76b21e33" sha1 (7th commit from the top). But when I do that, I lose several other commits that occurred before it. I realize that the reset is supposed to remove all changes that happened after the given commit, but in this case, it's removing those that occurred before too.

```
git reset --keep 1e1f9e389341e4161f2aa8d6f868346d76b21e33
git log --topo-order --reverse --pretty=oneline
50d035a5a12db8a0b23f4910a0e387f1ad38524c 0
c327029ebf8c442c45aaef090236650b50fb5e47 1
c64fcac8dd676084caacea4e20a0409926be7054 5
1e1f9e389341e4161f2aa8d6f868346d76b21e33 (HEAD -> master) 9
```

Where did the commits with messages "3", "7" and "11" go? How can I not lose those commits?

Comment: your log command is displaying commits in right order, also you are using --reverse, read first about git-log [git-log] (https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log)

Comment: Were commits 3, 7, and 11 from branch `b` or `d`?  You jumped to a point prior to merging `b` or `d`.

Comment: 3, 7 and 11 are commits that were merged from a different branch and yes they were merged after "1e1f9e389341e4161f2aa8d6f868346d76b21e33" was committed. How can I keep changes 3, 7 and 11?

Comment: Do you just want to make sure you can access those commits again easily in your repo?  Or do you actually want the contents of those commits to be in the current code-base where you reset to?

Comment: I want to have the changes made by those commits with the same sha1s they had before.

Comment: They will still exist, they are just no longer in a path to a `tag` or a `branch` so they are not being displayed when you do a `log`.  The changes that they contain will not be in your working directory, because you jumped back before you merge those changes in.  But the commits themselves should still exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are jumping to a point prior to those commits being `merged` into master, they are not being displayed in your `log`.  If you just want to keep an easy reference to commits `3`, `7`, and `11` in your repository, then you can create a `tag` or `branch` at the top-most commit (in this case `11`).

You would then need to `merge` it back into master; or `rebase` it on top of master  (but that will re-write the commits).

```
git tag <tag name> 1d7e5ea36224169db465d2e413c36895b02cafea
```

or

```
git branch <branch name> 1d7e5ea36224169db465d2e413c36895b02cafea
```

You will need to pass `--all` to your `log` command to see all the branches.

---

Instead of creating a `branch` or `tag` you could just `merge` commit `11` into master.

```
git merge 1d7e5ea36224169db465d2e413c36895b02cafea
```

Comment: When I merge these changes back to master, they will appear with new commit ids (I want all the changes to have their original commit ids). I want to have all the commits upto the point specified by any sha1. Is there any way that can be achieved?

Comment: Merging the commits from branch `b` should not rewrite them.  If you rebase branch `b` onto master, that will rewrite them.

Comment: This helps. I realized what I was doing wrong. Thanks!